# Android SDK 64 bit (Stand alone not ADT bundle) does it exist anymore?

Tags: android, windows, sdk, 64-bit

Maybe someone can assist me with this query. I'm setting Android up on a new Windows based laptop. However, recently the Android platform seems to have shifted into trying to urge users to download the ADT bundle, hiding the SDK only download from view.

I don't want the ADT budle because it contains an old version of Eclipse. Am I not wrong in thinking there was a specific 64bit Windows version of the SDK for download? Or was there never actually a 64bit version and I am miss-remembering?

I ask this because I cannot for the life of me see a 64 download for just the Android SDK. Only for the development bundle which I don't want or need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mis-remembering; there was always only a 32-bit version of the SDK. I think the only difference with the 64-bit bundle is that it uses 64-bit Eclipse.